# r as.Date returns previous day

Tags: r, as.date

as.Date(date1) is incorrectly returning the previous day.

I suspect it has got to do with time zones, but I am still learning the very basics of R so I have little chance of solving it on my own.

The code I use to produce this is:

```
> a <- (capital_paid_summary_per_loan$Arrears_Date[1])
> a
[1] "2015-08-31 SAST"
> as.Date(a)
[1] "2015-08-30"
>
```

As you can see, the date starts off to be "2015-08-31" but as.Date() changes it to one day prior.

Any advice is welcome

Comment: Try `as.Date("2015-08-31 SAST",tz='SAST')` : you have to specify the timezone in your case.

Comment: Another approach is `as.Date(format(a))` .

Comment: I liked @G.Grothendieck's approach; I think it's probably just a timezone nuance, as my dates were read in as `%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00` despite not having a time. While one could try and figure out some local timezone that lands on the right side of midnight, just ditching the time entirely seemed simpler (and worked).

Answer (score 1):

If

```
date <- "2015-08-31 SAST"
```

You could use:

```
as.Date("2015-08-31 SAST",tz='SAST')
```

Which specifies the timezone as SAST, or you could use:

```
as.Date(gsub(' SAST','',date))
```

Which will remove the timezone from part of the string and then convert to date.